# apple certificate signing request

Tags: iphone, certificate

I've built a dummy app and I'll like to test it on my iPhone. I know that I need to be enrolled in apple developer program and I’m in. I don’t have a MAC, so I had to rent one from macincloud[dot]com.

At this moment, I need to generate a signing certificate request, but I don’t have access to Keychain Access utility. The guys from macincloud offer access to the terminal, but not to Keychain Utility. I know that I need to use security tool from command line, but that’s all.

After 6 hours on two different days, I didn’t find any tutorial/description about how to use the security tool in order to generate the signing certificate request.

Do you have any idea about what do I need to do in command line to generate a signing certificate request?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Run the following in the terminal:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048
```

Save this private key file as you will use it later.

Run the following command, replacing the e-mail address, CN (certificate name), and C (country) values with your own:

```
openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -subj "/emailAddress=yourAddress@example.com, CN=John Doe, C=US"
```

Now in iOS Dev Portal, just use the generated CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest

Comment: Note that you must not generate a key longer than 2048 bytes. 

I've tried same thing with 4096 byte long key and Apple dev portal said that CSR is invalid. Same thing, but only with 2048 long key worked well.

My CSR was generated on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing this for Apple Push / APNS, you will also want to know about these 2 additional commands to generate the needed .p12 file:

```
openssl x509 -in XXXXX.cer -inform DER -out XXXXX.pem -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey XXXXX.key -in XXXXX.pem -out XXXXX.p12
```

where XXXXX is your "mykey" value and the xxxxx.cer file is what you download from the Apple portal.